# How to display all data and saved it in a text file?

Tags: python, mongodb

```
read = db.Student.find()
# use iter() to include loop for the first item index = 0
# use next(read, None) if you want to skip the first item index = 0
# object = iter(read)
object = iter(read)
'''Do a for loop to loop and print out each document'''
for object in read:
    with open("Student.txt", "w", newline="") as fp:
        read_records = str(object['_id']), str(object['ID']), object['item'], 
        str(object['qty'])
        r = ' '.join(read_records)
        print(r)
        fp.write(r)
        fp.close()
```

Firstly, I want to retrieve all data from collection.
Secondly, I want to save all retrieved data to a text file.
However, I could only manage to save the data of the last element. I could not save the first element to the forth element in the text file! 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reopening the output file for write in each iteration of the loop. Every iteration a new file is opened in *write* mode overwriting the existing "Students.txt".

```
read = db.Student.find()
# use iter() to include loop for the first item index = 0
# use next(read, None) if you want to skip the first item index = 0
# object = iter(read)
object = iter(read)
'''Do a for loop to loop and print out each document'''
with open("Student.txt", "w", newline="") as fp:
  for object in read:
    read_records = str(object['_id']), str(object['ID']), object['item'], 
    str(object['qty'])
    r = ' '.join(read_records)
    print(r)
    fp.write(r)
  fp.close()
```

This will fix your problem I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close files using `with open` it cares of it automatically

Try to use this:

```
read = db.Student.find()
    # use iter() to include loop for the first item index = 0
    # use next(read, None) if you want to skip the first item index = 0
    # object = iter(read)
    object = iter(read)
    '''Do a for loop to loop and print out each document'''
    with open("Student.txt", "w", newline="") as fp:
        for my_obj in read:
          read_records = str(my_obj['_id']), str(my_obj['ID']), my_obj['item'], 
          str(my_obj['qty'])
          r = ' '.join(read_records)
          print(r)
          fp.write(r)
```

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Haseeb ! It worked by printing out!! :)